# How does pyrosulfate compare to pyrophosphate?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, hydrolysis

That is, in terms of stability in aqueous solution and the energy released by the hydrolysis of the S-O-S bond compared with pyrophosphate hydrolysis. More specifically, could sulfates substitute phosphates in some kind of hypothetical biochemistry? AFAIK sulfates are generally not found in terrestrial biochemistry.

Comment: Biochemical systems can form sulfate and some organisms can even reduce sulfate as anaerobic oxygen sources.  But sulfate oligimers do not last long in water due to their Lewis acidity.

Comment: Pyrosulfates hydrolyse quickly. https://pubs.acs.org/doi/abs/10.1021/ic50004a019